# virtualbox enable network on windows 7

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I accidentally disabled virtualbox network via network and sharing center and as a result some of my virtual machines malfunctioned. I cant seem to find a way to enable the network again. Please let me know how to address this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to enable the virtualbox network adapter. You can follow any of them to re-enable it.

1. Go to `Network and Sharing Center--->Change adapter settings(on the left side)` and choose all of the network adapters related to your VirtualBox one by one,***RIGHT CLICK*** on them and enable them one by one!
2. Go to `My Computer(right-click)--->Manage--->Device Manager--->Switch to Network Adapters in Device Manager--->Choose all VirtualBox related adapters and enable them from there`.

I hope it helps you and also,reward me with an upvote,only if it does work.

Comment: Happy that it worked @redamakarem. THANKS anyway for the upvote though!